# I want to install a bruteforcer that uses pip in python, help me with it!

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, permissions, python

```
The directory '/home/anuj/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not 
owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. 
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. 
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

I get this error while running following python script:

```py
import os
os.system("sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential -y")
os.system("sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-setuptools -y")
os.system("pip install -U selenium && sudo apt-get install firefoxdriver -y")
os.system("pip install mechanize && pip install paramiko && pip install requests && pip install xmpppy==0.5.0rc1")
os.system("pip install stem && pip install pyvirtualdisplay && apt-get install xvfb")
```

Now I need to install, please help me!

Comment: Please update your question with error messages and Ubuntu version.

Comment: Who owns the mentioned directory ? Run `ls -l /home/anuj/.cache/pip/http` in a terminal, and update your question whit the output. Eventually run it for the parent directories too, that is without http in the end and again without pip,

Comment: You will need a `sudo` before the `apt-get install xvfb` in the last line of your quoted code.

Answer (score 1):

Take back ownership of pip's cache folder in your home directory using this command:

```
sudo chown -R anuj: /home/anuj/.cache/pip/
```

After that, `pip` should stop complaining.

For the future, do never run `sudo pip`. If you really need to use `pip` to install Python packages globally for all users, use `sudo -H pip` instead, so that it will use the root user's home directory as cache.

Comment: I found answer helpful , when I apply I found something shocking! Here's the Error:  "chown: cannot access '/home/anuj/.cache/pip/': No such file or directory"   When I manually open "home/anuj" , i don't see any folder like ".cache" ... Any solution ?

Comment: Files/directories starting with a dot (.) are hidden by default. You have to enable showing hidden files (probably in the View menu of your Files manager, or maybe by pressing Ctrl+H).

Comment: Oh sorry! My silly mistake , it worked.. Thanks!